# The SAT problem can be reduced to the complement of the halting problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

The SAT is in NP, I suppose that the complement of the halting problem is in coNP-hard. I suppose the answer is no because SAT is not in coNP, but I am not sure.

Comment: Do you mean under PTIME reductions?

Comment: Yes, PTIME reduction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $T$ be a fixed Turing machine that decides SAT. From $T$ it is easy to construct a Turing machine $T'$ that takes SAT instance $x$ as input and halts iff $T(x)$ rejects.

In other words, given a SAT instance $x$,  $x$ is satisfiable iff the pair $\langle T', x \rangle$ is in the complement of the Halting language.

Answer (score 5):

A PTIME reduction from $\text{SAT}$ to $\overline{HALT_{TM}}$ operates as follows. On input $\varphi$, the reduction outputs $\langle M, \varphi\rangle$, where $M$ is a constant TM that operates as follows. On input $\varphi$, $M$ goes over all assignments to variables of $\varphi$, and checks whether $\varphi$ is satisfiable. If $\varphi$ is satisfiable, $M$ gets stuck in a loop, otherwise, $M$ halts.
It is not hard to see that the reduction is polynomial in $|\varphi|$. Indeed, the description of $M$ does not depend on $\varphi$. Also, $M$ halts on $\varphi$ iff $\phi \in \overline{\text{SAT}}$, and thus $\phi \in \text{SAT}$ iff $\langle M, \varphi\rangle \in \overline{HALT_{TM}}$.

The point here is that we do not care if $M$ is efficient as the reduction outputs its description, which costs us a constant time in $|\varphi|$.

Comment: Sorry, for the duplicated answer. Your answer only showed up after I submitted mine (usually there is a little banner notifying of new answers).

Comment: @Steven No problem!